# JSP code to generate excel sheet of data retrieved in jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, excel, jsp

I want to export data to Excel sheet

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@include file="connection.jsp" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%
    String ht = (String)session.getAttribute("ht");
    %>
    <table border="1">
    <%
    pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from attendance where ht='"+ht+"'");
    res = pst.executeQuery();
    if(res.next())
    {
        String uname = res.getString(2);
        %>
        <b>Student Name:<%=uname%></b>

        <%
        String hlt = res.getString(1);
        %>
        <b>Hallticket:<%=hlt%></b>
        <tr><th>CG</th><th>CD</th><th>MPI</th><th>HCI</th><th>WT</th><th>MPI-Lab</th><th>CT=Lab</th><th>WT-Lab</th></tr>
        <%
        String cg = res.getString(3);
        String cd = res.getString(4);
        String mpi = res.getString(5);
        String hci = res.getString(6);
        String wt = res.getString(7);
        String mpi_lab = res.getString(8);
        String ct_lab = res.getString(9);
        String wt_lab = res.getString(10);
        %>
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><%=cg%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=cd%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=mpi%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=hci%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=wt%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=mpi_lab%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=ct_lab%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=wt_lab%></td>
        </tr>
        <br/><br/>

        <%
    }
    %>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want the data that is retrieved from database and displayed in table should be printed on excel sheet
Please can any one tell me how to do it ... :(
I used mysql databse.

Answer (score 0):

You must add following lines to your jsp page which you want to export to excel:

```
response.setContentType("application/xls");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=File.xls");
```

Or you must learn about [`POI`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/)

And you must change `if(res.next())` with `while(res.next())`

Comment: Headers appears in excel?

Comment: Are you sure your select query is correct and give result?

Comment: the problem is that your sql query has no result,fix this and you get excel excel with files.

Comment: where shpuld i add this code at begining of code or at after sql query

Comment: no still,while iam opening excel file it's saying "The file you trying to open 'file.xls' ,is in a diff format than specified by the file extension" and showing yes,no,cancel control buttons when i click on yes no data was there inside empty sheet

normally the output was alright it displaying in a table ,the query was working fine

Comment: after ,clicking on yes only i got nothing 
I think it need any other code that is not present in my code
:( iam v.sorry but iam unable to get
thanq for ur answers
If my code needs any changes plz tell me

Comment: did you change `if` to `while`?

Answer (score 0):

*Try using a servlet to do the Excel writing.*

> You could use it as a JSP:Include in your existing page if you wanted
>   to.

From the servlet you'll have to do something like this:

```
ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
/*
* get data 
*/

if (data != null) {
for (int i=0; i data.length; i++) {
   String dataRow = "";
   for (int j = 0; j data[0].length; j++) {
       dataRow += data[i][j] + "\t";// add tab delimiter
   }
   out.println(dataRow);// print data
}
} else {//Bad data...
   out.println("No data to report.");
}

out.flush();
```

Hope it helps you. :)